# Promises - catch is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Why is it that the following code doesn't catch the exception being thrown?

```
$http.get(null)        // <- this throws a fit
.catch(function (e) {
  console.log(e);      // <- this is not being triggered
});
```

> Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url must be a string or a $sce trusted object.  Received: null
>   https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$http/badreq?p0=null

Comment: I *think* you're confusing try/catch with the `catch` handler on your promise. The first is throwing a fit because null isn't an acceptable input argument. You would need to wrap the entire thing in a `try {...} catch (err) {...}`

Comment: The `$http.get` method is throwing the error *before* it creates and returns a promise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to understand that this `catch` is waiting for a "rejection" from your `get` call.

In other words, your `$http.get` is triggering an error and never returning a promise...this way, you can't execute a catch straight from an error, get it?

If you have `$http.get("xyz")` it will then do its thing and reject, therefore, being caught by your catch.

What you are doing results in this

```
// step 1
$http.get(null)
    .catch()

// step 2
ERROR
    .catch() // will not even get here, but if it did, it wouldn't work either
```

While, if your `get` could work, but rejected, you would have:

```
// step 1
$http.get('someFailingURL')
    .catch()

// step 2
RejectedPromise
    .catch() // gonna work :)
```

If your url comes from a different source (and that's why you get a `null` value for it some times) you should probably validate it before trying and getting it, like so:

```
if (yourVariableURL !== null) {
    $http.get(yourVariableURL)
        .catch()
} else {
    console.log('Invalid url');
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`.catch()` is not a replacement for normal `try` `catch`.

**It is specifically for handling exceptional circumstances that occurred during the promise resolution process.**

In this case, the exception (throwing a fit) is happening outside the promise resolution process.

Your supplying invalid input to the `$http.get` method causing an exception before an XHR even gets created, *not* something going wrong with the HTTP request or any subsequent processing.

Here is an equivalent of what is happening:

```
try {
  $http.get(throwAnException()) 
    // .catch isn't even being evaluated!
    .catch(function(e) { 
      console.error(e); // no chance of being called      
    });

} catch (e) {
  // I would be evaluated
  console.error(e);
}

function throwAnException() {
  throw "An error before we even start";
}
```

Comment: @BShaps Appreciated :) First draft was rushed and on review definitely needed a bit of code to illustrate clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This will throw Error: $http:badreq Bad Request Configuration.  It has issue at request parameter level where string/url is expected but not null. Hence not going inside the block. That is the reason it is not triggering catch.

The error will be thrown by Angular is as below -

> Http request configuration url must be a string or a $sce trusted object.  Received: null

This error occurs when the request configuration parameter passed to the $http service is not a valid object. $http expects a single parameter, the request configuration object, but received a parameter that was not an object or did not contain valid properties.

To resolve this error, make sure you pass a valid request configuration object to $http.

Additionally, if required to catch the issue with this block of code itself, wrap it in try-catch block.